# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el mes anterior en formato "YYYY-mm"?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo obtener el mes anterior en formato `YYYY-mm` en una fecha dada con formato `YYYY-mm-dd`?.

Sé hacerlo en PHP pero en javascript estoy muy verde. Necesito ayuda, por favor.

Os dejo el código PHP por si sirve de pista, ya que seguro me explico muy mal:

```
function cierre($fecha){ 
    $date=date_create($fecha);
    date_sub($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 MONTH"));
    return date_format($date,"Y-m");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El equivalente en javascript sería:

```js
function cierre(fecha) { 
  var date = new Date(fecha);
  /* Javascript recalculará la fecha si el mes es menor de 0 (enero) 
    o mayor de 11 (diciembre) */
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  /* Obtenemos la fecha en formato YYYY-mm */
  return date.toISOString().substring(0, 7);
}
console.log(cierre('2018-01-01'));
```

Javascript no dispone de una función para dar formato a una fecha como PHP, pero se puede usar [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) para generar la fecha en formato [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.mmmZ) y quedarte con la parte inicial con [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

El funcionamiento de [`Date.setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) permite indicar meses fuera de rango para recalcular el año en curso:

> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, `setMonth()` attempts to update the date information in the `Date` object accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for `monthValue`, the year will be incremented by 1, and 3 will be used for month.

En castellano:

> Si especificas un parámetro fuera del rango esperado, `setMonth()` intentará actualizar la información de la fecha en el objeto `Date` de manera acorde. Por ejemplo, si usas 15 para `monthValue`, el año será incrementado en 1 y se usará 3 para el mes.

Answer (score 0):

Variando la de Sergio (que no funciona porque fecha.getMonth() devuelve el mes de 0 a 11, y hace además alguna cosa extraña:

```js
    var fecha = new Date(); 
    fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() - 1); 
    console.log(fecha.getFullYear() + '-'+ (fecha.getMonth()+1));
```

Comment: perfecto, muchísimas gracias. Es lo q

Comment: Considera marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Esto hará el trabajo:

```
var prev = (a = new Date(), b = a.setMonth(a.getMonth() - 1)) => `${a.getFullYear()}-${a.getMonth() + 1}-${a.getDate()}`;
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes seguir el siguiente modelo.

```js
var strFecha = '2018/01/09'
    var fecha = new Date(strFecha); //'yyyy-mm-dd'
    fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() - 1); //mes anterior
    console.log(fecha.getFullYear() + '-'+ (fecha.getMonth()+1));
```

Pero esto no te devolvera el formato YYYY-mm, para ello existen librerias para formatear, implementar tu mismo la funcion que lo haga.

Answer (score -1):

Lo hice rápido, aparentemente funciona. Revísalo.

```js
function calcular(fecha) {

  var fechaHoy = new Date(fecha);

  var year = (fechaHoy.getMonth() - 1 == -1) ? fechaHoy.getUTCFullYear() - 1 : fechaHoy.getUTCFullYear();

  var month = (fechaHoy.getMonth() - 1 == -1) ? 12 : fechaHoy.getMonth();

  if (month < 10) {

    month = String('0' + month);

  }

  return year + '-' + month

}

console.warn(calcular('2018-01-09'));
console.warn(calcular('2018-07-19'));
console.warn(calcular('2018-12-30'));
```